How to run conan install to build one package with a different compiler.cppstd
I'm building a number of packages with conan install, the packages are defined in a conanfile.py. One of the packages needs to be built with a different compiler.cppstd setting than the rest.
How can I set a per-package compiler.cppstd value? I tried conan install ... -s <package-name>:compiler.cppstd=gnu17 but it had no effect.

You have to use -s <package-name>/*:compiler.cppstd=gnu17: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/profiles.html#profile-patterns Plus, in case having a pre-built package with a compatible cppstd available in your Conan cache, Conan client will use that cached version first, you will need to build from source using the specific cppstd to make it available.

Thanks, @uilianries! Is it possible to do this in conanfile.py, too?

Changing settings in a recipe is an anti-pattern: https://docs.conan.io/2/knowledge/guidelines.html#forbidden-practices. Instead, you should rise a ConanInvalidConfiguration in case fmt is not available by using the specific cppstd: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/methods/validate.html
What you can do is create a specific Conan profile, where you can point the settings, as I pointed out in my previous comment.
